# How to give each user permission? android studio application

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to develop an android application which contain admin login and user login..each admin can add posts contain (image description of image and some other information), also can delete posts. while the  the user can just review or see this posts how to give each one a specific permission can any one explain to me how i should start ?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is create a class , for example, AbilityProvider and list some public static Constant variables like "DELETE", "ADD", "MODIFY", "VIEW" and all.

Now you can create other 2 activities like "Admin" and "User". In admin, initialize all the constant variables to 1 and in user class, initialize the specific constant variables to 1 , rest to 0.

Now play with them as you want.